# how to create an asynchronous connection to the server without sending and ajax request after every 2 seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I created a message chat application with JQuery. But my app is crashing due to the number of Ajax request and sending to the server.
I tried increasing the time interval but the app was no more getting messages in real time.

Comment: try using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or even better [Socket.io](https://socket.io) for passing messages between client and server instead of Long Polling your server for updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use socket.io, and call for fill msgs on the basis of user typo only, means when other starts typing then ajax will call otherwise not. and for notification you can use Firebase.

You can follow 
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/creating-a-real-time-chat-application-with-ionic-2-and-socket-io/

I think this will help you